# Threads in Java Application

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

Hey guys. I am trying to write a file transfer application in java and so far it's been ok: i start the server and the client and then transfer the file. I'm having trouble connecting multiple clients to the same server. I googled it and found out that my server side should run in threads. How can i do that with my application? Thanks.

Server:

```
package filesharing;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Server
{
    public static void main(String args[])throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("Server pornit...");

        /* Asteapta pe portul  1412 */

        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(1412);

        /* Accepta socketul */

        Socket sk = server.accept();

        System.out.println("Client acceptat de catre server pe portul: "+server.getLocalPort());
        InputStream input = sk.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader inReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sk.getInputStream()));
        BufferedWriter outReader = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(sk.getOutputStream()));

        /* Citeste calea fisierului */
        String filename = inReader.readLine();

        if ( !filename.equals("") ){

            /* Trimite status READY catre client */

            outReader.write("READY\n");
            outReader.flush();
        }

        /* Creaza fila noua in directorul tmp */
        FileOutputStream wr = new FileOutputStream(new File("C://tmp/" + filename));

        byte[] buffer = new byte[sk.getReceiveBufferSize()];

        int bytesReceived = 0;

        while((bytesReceived = input.read(buffer))>0)
        {
            /* Scrie in fila */
           wr.write(buffer,0,bytesReceived);
        }
    }
}
```

Client:

```
package filesharing;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Client extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JTextField txtFile;

    public static void main(String args[]){

        /* Creare pannel client */

        Client clientForm = new Client();
        clientForm.Display();
    }

    public void Display(){

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Client");

        FlowLayout layout = new FlowLayout();
        layout.setAlignment(FlowLayout.LEFT);

        JLabel lblFile = new JLabel("Fisier:");

        txtFile = new JTextField();
        txtFile.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,30));

        JButton btnTransfer = new JButton("Transfer");
        btnTransfer.addActionListener(this);

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(layout);
        mainPanel.add(lblFile);
        mainPanel.add(txtFile);
        mainPanel.add(btnTransfer);

        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        /* Casuta File Open Dialog pentru selectarea fisierului */

        JFileChooser fileDlg = new JFileChooser();
        fileDlg.showOpenDialog(this);
        String filename = fileDlg.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
        txtFile.setText(filename);

        try{

            /* Incearca conectarea la serverul localhost pe portul 1412 */

            Socket sk = new Socket("localhost", 1412);
            OutputStream output = sk.getOutputStream();

            /* Trimite numele fisierului la server */

            OutputStreamWriter outputStream = new OutputStreamWriter(sk.getOutputStream());
            outputStream.write(fileDlg.getSelectedFile().getName() + "\n");
            outputStream.flush();

            /* Asteapta raspunsul de la server */

            BufferedReader inReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sk.getInputStream()));

            String serverStatus = inReader.readLine(); // Citeste prima linie

            /* Daca serverul e READY trimite fisierul */

            if ( serverStatus.equals("READY") ){

                FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(filename);

                byte[] buffer = new byte[sk.getSendBufferSize()];

                int bytesRead = 0;

                while((bytesRead = file.read(buffer))>0)
                {
                    output.write(buffer,0,bytesRead);
                }

                output.close();
                file.close();
                sk.close();

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Transfer complet");

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            /* Catch pentru eventuale erori */
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Now that you've found you need to use threads, the next step is to read the [Java threading tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/).  It would be useless to just get someone to write it for you if you don't understand how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're right if you want to handle multiple connections you need to run every server request in a single thread. The theory behind is the following ...

```
while (true)
    accept a connection ;
    create a thread to deal with the client ;
end while
```

or more java-alike:

```
while(true) {
     clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
     YourWorkerThread thread = new YourWorkerThread(clientSocket);
     thread.start();
}
```

Where ...
`YourWorkerThread` is a class that extends `Thread` and implements a method `run` where the logic of the server is located.

So looking at your server-side code, all the lines of code after `Socket sk = server.accept();` should go in the method `run` of a class that extends `Thread`.

Comment: Done. Thanks a lot. Another question. Is Java able to open from the client-side a JFileChooser with the files-structure from the server(eg i want to connect to server, browse for a file on the server and copy it to the client).

Comment: No, that is definitely not possible. Unless you implement a client that asks for the files in the directory and lists them in the JFileChooser in the client. In summary you need to implement the communication protocol. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732179/jfilechooser-browsing-a-remote-file-system

Comment: Thanks for the help. I wonder if RMI would help solving that problem.

Answer (score 0):

You might implement the interface `Runnable` und start the actual work using `new Thread(myRunnable).start()` - that's the simple version. Make sure that your code is thread safe or it will interfere with your other threads.

Answer (score 0):

To [define and start a thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html) you need an implementation of the class [Runnable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) that is passed to a [Thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) instance on which you call [start](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start%28%29).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960238/how-do-i-add-thread-to-my-server) is very similar and will provide you a place to start.  One answer points to [a socket tutorial that shows how to use multiple clients](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html).  If you haven't read the Socket tutorials, you definitely should.

But don't stop at knowing just the basics of threading or you'll run into problems.  Concurrency is a hard problem.  You will want to read up on the great world of [Java concurrency](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/).

Ideally you will be inspired enough to read [Java Concurrency in Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601), an amazing reference on concurrency in Java.